# Accessing pointer type char array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am working on a keypad program which will work like an old flip phone to input characters into an array. For this assignment I am REQUIRED to use pointer types so I can't just change the array to a normal char type to solve the problem. 
The problem I am running into is that after I input the first character, let's say "55", the program correctly stores 'J' into the first slot of the 'month' array. However, the next time I input a value, it runs the correct switch case, but then it gives me an access violation to access the second index `month[1]` and breaks. I made sure that my input is clearing at the end of the switch, and it is attempting to run the correct case, so I am sure it's not related to the switch statement. I am sure it has something to do with my misunderstanding of pointers. I don't understand why it doesn't input the second character, but has no problem inputting the first character.

I will attach the code in question below.

HEADER:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class keypad
{

private:
    char* month[45];
    int* input;
    int index = 0;

public:
    keypad();
    ~keypad();
    void getinput(int);
    void getmonth();
    void print()const;
    void clear();


};
```

IMPLEMENTATION:

```
#include "keypad.h"

keypad::keypad() {
    *month = new char;
    input = new int;

}

keypad::~keypad() {
    delete month;
    delete input;
    input = NULL;
    *month = NULL;
}


void keypad::getinput(int a) {

    *input = a;

}


void keypad::getmonth() {

    switch (*input) {
    case(2):
        *month[index] = '2'; //The exception would be thrown right here if my second input is 2.
        index++;

        break;
    case(22):
        *month[index] = 'A';
        index++;

        break;
    case(222):
        *month[index] = 'B';
        index++;

        break;
    case(2222):
        *month[index] = 'C';
        index++;

        break;
    case(3):
        *month[index] = '3';
        index++;

        break;
    case(33):
        *month[index] = 'D';
        index++;

        break;
    case(333):
        *month[index] = 'E';
        index++;

        break;
    case(3333):
        *month[index] = 'F';
        index++;

        break;
    case(4):
        *month[index] = '4';
        index++;

        break;
    case(44):
        *month[index] = 'G';
        index++;

        break;
    case(444):
        *month[index] = 'H';
        index++;

        break;
    case(4444):
        *month[index] = 'I';
        index++;

        break;
    case(5):
        *month[index] = '5';
        index++;

        break;
    case(55):
        *month[index] = 'J';
        index++;

        break;
    case(555):
        *month[index] = 'K';
        index++;

        break;
    case(5555):
        *month[index] = 'L';
        index++;

        break;
    case(6):
        *month[index] = '6';
        index++;

        break;
    case(66):
        *month[index] = 'M';
        index++;

        break;
    case(666):
        *month[index] = 'N';
        index++;

        break;
    case(6666):
        *month[index] = 'O';
        index++;

        break;
    case(7):
        *month[index] = '7';
        index++;

        break;
    case(77):
        *month[index] = 'P';
        index++;

        break;
    case(777):
        *month[index] = 'Q';
        index++;

        break;
    case(7777):
        *month[index] = 'R';
        index++;

        break;
    case(77777):
        *month[index] = 'S';
        index++;

        break;
    case(8):
        *month[index] = '8';
        index++;

        break;
    case(88):
        *month[index] = 'T';
        index++;

        break;
    case(888):
        *month[index] = 'U';
        index++;

        break;
    case(8888):
        *month[index] = 'V';
        index++;

        break;
    case(9):
        *month[index] = 'W';
        index++;

        break;
    case(99):
        *month[index] = 'X';
        index++;

        break;
    case(999):
        *month[index] = 'Y';
        index++;

        break;
    case(9999):
        *month[index] = 'Z';
        index++;

        break;
    case(1):
        *month[index] = '1';
        index++;

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    *input = NULL;
}

void keypad::print()const{

    cout << *month[index - 1] << endl;

}

void keypad::clear() {
    delete month;
    *month = NULL;

}
```

MAIN:

```
int main() {

    cout << "READ ME" << endl;
    cout << "For the purposes of this program, assume that ABC is on the number '2'." << endl;
    cout << "Also, assume that the first press of any number key will input the number itself." << endl;
    cout << "If your input is invalid, a character will not be saved, you may hit enter to restart the input for that character." << endl;
    cout << "You will input the number for a single character then press enter to save that character. These must be done in order." << endl;
    cout << "At any time after inputting a character, you may exit the program or clear the memory and input another word." << endl;
    int tempinput;

    keypad a;
    bool loop = true;
    bool endword = false;
    bool toclear = false;
    while (loop) {
        cout << "input the numeric code for your desired character, EX: 22 = 'A'." << endl;
        cin >> tempinput;
        a.getinput(tempinput);
        a.getmonth();
        a.print();
    }
}
```

The main problem happens in the implementation file where it will throw the exception on the line where the array is assigned a character. However, this ONLY happens on the second character, and the first one is stored no problem.

[image: here is the error in Visual Studio]

edit:

I changed the constructor code to initialize all indices of `month` instead of just one via creating a for loop to initialize each `month[i]` to new char.

I now have another question and I feel it would be smarter if I just asked here because it is the same project. What could be causing an ofstream object to not be written to? the only time it is used is in my main, and I closed it at the end.

```
int tempinput;

    keypad a;
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("output.txt");

    while (true) {
        cout << "input the numeric code for your desired character, EX: 22 = 'A'." << endl;
        cin >> tempinput;
        outfile << tempinput;
        a.getinput(tempinput);
        a.getmonth();
        a.print();

    }

    outfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Seems like you only allocated memory for the very first pointer-to-char in the array.

Comment: `*month = new char;` is equivalent to `month[0] = new char;` You'll need to loop through your array and give each dereferenced item a `new char`.

Comment: alright, I'm going to go do that and I'll edit the post. :) thanks